# Get difference using map in groovy?

Tags: json, groovy, comparison, response, difference

These are the responses

```
RESPONSE_1 = [fastfood:[[country:Canada,owner:[[name:John,totalEmployees:100,age:60],contractor:unknown]]] 

RESPONSE_2 = [fastfood:[[country:Canada,owner:[[name:John,totalEmployees:100],[name:Mike,totalEmployees:80]],contractor:unknown]]]
```

Expected output in ${res1Diff}:

```
[age:60]
```

Expected output in ${res2Diff}:

```
[name:Mike,totalEmployees:80]
```

This is my 1st code, it returns null

```
stage('comparison') {
steps {
  script {
   if (RESPONSE_1 == RESPONSE_2) {
    println("Matched")
   } else {
    println("Does not match")
    def res1Diff = RESPONSE_1.minus(RESPONSE_2)
    def res2Difd = RESPONSE_2.minus(RESPONSE_1)
    echo "${res1Diff}"
    echo "${res2Diff}"
   }
  }
}
}
```

Tried this one too, same it returns null (using .remove()) or error msg *hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature method: ....* (using .minus() or .removeAll())

```
RESPONSE_1.each { entry ->
def res2Diff = RESPONSE_2.minus("$entry")
}
echo "${res2Diff}"
```

I also tried this one, same output as the other

```
def res1 = res1.remove{entry -> 
res2.contains("$entry.key:$entry.value")
}
echo "${res1Difference}"
```

Comment: what about the library: https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert

Comment: Do i need to import anything on my jenkinsfile? It wont work by simply writing **JSONAssert.assertEquals(RESPONSE_1,RESPONSE_2,false)**

Comment: You have to download jar and add it to classpath in Jenkins.